# Pattern to detect Ansible failure

Tags: ansible

I have a an Ansible playbook quite big with a laot of template and it generates tons of logs (hundreds of thousands of lines in my log file)

Whenever a task fail, I can spot it with failed=

My problem is how to see where the error as of today, all I'm doing is scrolling the log and pray for my eyes to find the error but when you have that quantity of lines, it can take time and very frustrating.

Is there any pattern I should look for to find where the error is?

Thanks in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

By default, Ansible stops after the first failed task...

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html

> Ansible normally has defaults that make sure to check the return codes
>   of commands and modules and it fails fast – forcing an error to be
>   dealt with unless you decide otherwise.

If your playbook handles a lot of targets and you want to stop everything at the first failure on any target, you an use `any_errors_fatal: true` play option.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#aborting-the-play